# js. программная активация события input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input, на него подвешено событие `input`, все нормально работает когда пользователь вводит текст с клавиатуры, но вот при программном изменении поля, например `input.value = 'тратата';` событие не работает, как это можно исправить?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в одном из полей изменить что-либо, то происходит нужное событие, при нажатии + или - происходит программное изменение поля, но событие input не происходит.

P.S. 
Функция обработчик неизвестна где находится и как называется, скрипт не мой.

ЗЫ Код следующий: 
У инпута есть селектор класса, я думаю будет что-то вроде такого:

```
$('.class').on("input", function(){
     alert('ура'); 
});
```

При программном изменении `alert('ура');` не происходит.

Comment: добавь код, !!!

Comment: ок, добавил уже пример

Comment: твой пример у меня работает, подозреваю, что ты не правильно подключил JQ, подключи его в head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы программно вызвать какое-либо событие на элементе jQuery существует метод [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('.class').on('input', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});

$('.class').val('123').trigger('input');
```

Comment: @Shillkas верно подмечено :) Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо, ваш вариант действительно работает, не думал что все будет так просто :)